# What is the best way to implement dynamic CSS & SVG values (PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, css, svg

I'm working a rudimentary system for holding pages on a number of domains.  I intend to populate values in a DB and use these values to produce a page.

The values I'd use would include colour values which I'd like to then inject in to the CSS file and an SVG file.

Currently I'm thinking of using .htaccess to process .css/.svg as PHP and drop the values in from there, but is there a more efficient/elegant way without having to process these file formats as PHP?

All advice appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: I should add, would JavaScript be useful for this?

Comment: You can edit your question for additions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to make this all PHP (or server side at least). You can use PHP to output both CSS and SVG. You can make files for either and just execute them as were they PHP. Most content will be static, but in a couple of places you can fill in the values using PHP.

For CSS you could take a look at LessCSS (or LessPHP).

Anyhow, I wouldn't use Javascript for this, ever. At least, not client side Javascript. :) This should typically be done on the server.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm currently writing a script that makes the SVG file on the fly (it's a basic gradient, 1kb).  The CSS could be made the same way.  Just worried about performance if this grows to include multiple pages/extended CSS.

If I were re-writing CSS/SVG on each request would that seriously degrade performance if these files we less than 10kb combined?

Comment: Well, you don't have to write them to disk at each request. You can just put them trough. The other way around: if you do write them to disk, you don't have to generate them on each request. You can cache the generated file and put that throught using file_put_content or so. Just check if the source file has changed since the last request. If you got MemCache or a MySQL memory table, you can use that for caching too.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much. Only when you get hundreds of simultaneous visitors, you'll need this kind of caching. Usually it's not a problem at all. Your regular pages are generated using PHP as well, aren't they?

Comment: Thanks all.  Yeah, I'm going to write them out for now, and if it grows then I'll introduce caching or timestamp checking.  Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I haven't really worked with svg but from looking at some sample code I don't think this matters for my answer.

Something about php in your css file doesn't sit right with me. I've tried it before and it didn't make things easier. CSS files don't parse php by default and even though you can make them it becomes easy to forget how you set things up. Here's how I would approach it...

If parts of the css is going to be different for each page, then it would make sense to declare that in the head of your html/svg page. You  can link your default stylesheet with almost all your styling and then just override the specific color values in the head of your page. Or even inline if that makes your output easier. You won't have to worry about having php output in multiple files for the same page.

Or, if you have a limited set of styles that are going to be reused, there's nothing wrong with giving them all class names in the same file. Then you can just output the class name with php and use the same css file for everything. This would keep you organized and the file would have to be pretty huge for the unused classes to affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about doing something like to this. But in my case I use a CMS called MODx.

You could create a css file in MODx and then use php snippets to fill in the css file when it's called. My thinking was to have most of the css file not-dynamic and then have one or several snippets of php that would return specific css according to the page a user was on, the variables I send the snippet, etc.

Personal Note: MODx is a super powerful CMS, that you can do pretty much anything with.